# Getting Registry Key Value From Multiple PCs

Tags: registry

I am trying to find computers within a domain that have a lower program version than required.

So I need to get a registry key for the version number of an application from multiple windows devices.

Ideally the script would import a file with multiple machine names, log in and export the registry key value "version" from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Program\Name to a different file alongside the machine name. (Ideally it would also output which machines the process failed on)

I have searched to no avail.

Cheers.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question and be better asked in one of the other SE sites.

Comment: Apologies, I scoured the net for the answer but the closest I got was this site! Which site do you recommend?

Comment: Maybe something like http://serverfault.com/ or checkout the index at https://stackexchange.com/sites